# Where do I find Sql Server metadata for column datatypes?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, metadata

I know that I can get access to column properties via:

```
select * 
from sysobjects
```

What I can't find however is information about where to get the type and type length for a column, ie: in

```
FOO VARCHAR(80)
```

Where do I look to find the "VARCHAR(80)" part of the type declaration in the metadata tables?

I tried looking at the systypes table, but its values for xtype do not match up to the values of xtype in the sysobjects table.

*I do not have access to the original SQL used to build these tables nor do I have any admin rights.

If you're familiar with DB2 I'm looking for the equivalent to

```
select name,
       coltype,
       length,
  from sysibm.syscolumns
where tbname = 'FOO'
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are close.  You can look at `sys.columns` to get the columns.

You can filter on a table with `OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('dbo.Foo')`.

You can get the length from `sys.columns`.  The data type is in the `user_type_id` field.  The keys for that field are in `sys.types`.

In its entirety you can do:

```
select object_NAME(c.object_id), c.name, t.name, c.max_length
from sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.types t
    ON t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
```

As a side note, in SQL Server the system tables are deprecated (i.e. `syscolumns`, `sysobjects`) and it's recommended as a best practice to use the views instead, `sys.columns`, `sys.objects`, etc.

This will give you Table, column, data type, and maxlength for each one.

Answer (score 13):

The correct way to do this is to join to **user**_type_id in the sys.types table:

```
select object_NAME(c.object_id), c.name, t.name, c.max_length
from sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.types t
    ON t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
```

`user_type_id` is identical to system_type_id for system types - see documentation:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188021.aspx

Comment: This is the better answer. JNK's anwer gave me duplicates

Answer (score 4):

To build on the answers above, it's often useful to get the column data type in the same format that you need to declare columns.

For example, `varchar(50)`, `varchar(max)`, `decimal(p, s)`.

This allows you to do that:

```
SELECT 
  [Name]         = c.[name]
, [Type]         = 
    CASE 
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('varchar', 'char') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + IIF(c.max_length = -1, 'max', CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(25))) + ')' 
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('nvarchar','nchar') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + IIF(c.max_length = -1, 'max', CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(25)))+ ')'      
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('decimal', 'numeric') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS VARCHAR(25)) + ', ' + CAST(c.[scale] AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')'
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('datetime2') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + CAST(c.[scale] AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')'
      ELSE tp.[name]
    END
, [RawType]      = tp.[name]
, [MaxLength]    = c.max_length
, [Precision]    = c.[precision]
, [Scale]        = c.scale
FROM sys.tables t 
JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
JOIN sys.types tp ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
WHERE s.[name] = 'dbo' AND t.[name] = 'MyTable'
```

Comment: binary length missing

Comment: After some testing, adding `binary` and `varbinary` to the first case condition (along with `varchar` and `char`) covers all datatypes