# Search a column name in a few tables,not the whole database SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT something 
FROM table1, table2, table 
WHERE tableColumn = "tableName"
```

Comment: What?  Are you asking for all tables that have a specific column name in them?  Are you asking for a code generator that looks for all tables with a specific column name and then does a query on those tables?  Are you asking for a join where table1, table2, and table3 all have the same value in a column?

Comment: " Are you asking for all tables that have a specific column name in them?" yes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9180068/2589202

Answer (score 0):

You could do something crazy-complicated regarding the schema tables, if necessary, but this should work in a pinch:

```
select <something> 
    from table1
    where 
        tableColumn = "tableName"
union all
select <something>
    from table2
    where 
        tableColumn = "tableName"
union all
select <something>
    from table3
    where
        tableColumn = "tableName"
```

Just make sure you select the same type of column from each of the queries in the union.