# Where can I verify SQL key type codes?

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2017

Based on [SQL Server Schema Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-schema-collections#indexcolumns) I'd like to use `sqlConnection.GetSchema("IndexColumns");` to determine which columns are primary keys.

I did some experiments and found that with the above request I get a data table with the following information:

```
table_catalog   table_schema   table_name              column_name ordinal_position   KeyType   index_name
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TestDb          dbo            TestTableWithPrimaryKey     Id              1             56      PK_TestTableWithPrimaryKey
```

I guess `KeyType = 56` stands for *primary-key* but this is only deduced from this table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTableWithPrimaryKey]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Foo] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTableWithPrimaryKey] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I'd like to verify that my finding is correct before I actually use it in any project. Is there some place where I can get all key types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at the internal `SqlMetaDataFactory`  the call to `sqlConnection.GetSchema("IndexColumns");` does lookup which command to execute as found in the resource file `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlMetaData.xml` and that will show us for entry *IndexColumns*

```xml
 <MetaDataCollections>
    <CollectionName>IndexColumns</CollectionName>
    <NumberOfRestrictions>5</NumberOfRestrictions>
    <NumberOfIdentifierParts>4</NumberOfIdentifierParts>
    <PopulationMechanism>SQLCommand</PopulationMechanism>
    <PopulationString>EXEC sys.sp_indexcolumns_managed @Catalog, @Owner, @Table, @ConstraintName, @Column</PopulationString>
    <MinimumVersion>10.00.0000</MinimumVersion>
  </MetaDataCollections>
```

This means that it will execute `EXEC sys.sp_indexcolumns_managed`. That stored procedure will reveal with `EXEC sp_helptext 'sys.sp_indexcolumns_managed'` that it selects from `sys.spt_indexcolumns_view_managed` and that view is defined as:

```sql
select distinct 
    db_Name() as constraint_catalog, 
    constraint_schema = SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id), 
    constraint_name = x.name, 
    table_catalog  = db_name(), 
    table_schema = SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id), 
    table_name = o.name, 
    column_name = c.name, 
    ordinal_position = xc.key_ordinal, 
    KeyType  = c.system_type_id, 
    index_name = x.name 
from 
    sys.objects o INNER JOIN sys.indexes x ON
        (
            o.object_id = x.object_id AND
            o.type in ('U')
        )  INNER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns xc ON
        (
            xc.object_id = x.object_id AND
            xc.index_id = x.index_id
        ) INNER JOIN
    sys.columns c ON
        (
            o.object_id = c.object_id AND
            xc.column_id = c.column_id
        )
```

(You can find its definition with `SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('sys.sp_indexcolumns_managed'));` because it is part of the [Resource Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/resource-database))

Now we can see that the column KeyType is projected over `sys.columns.system_type_id` which is documented in [sys.columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql) as

> ID of the system type of the column.

and [Where do I find Sql Server metadata for column datatypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179990/where-do-i-find-sql-server-metadata-for-column-datatypes) details that joining with `sys.types` will give you the information of the type of the column.

Armed with that information we can already conclude that *I guess KeyType = 56 stands for primary-key* is not true and running

```
select name, system_type_id, user_type_id, schema_id, max_length,  precision scale
from sys.types 
where system_type_id = 56
```

will return

```
name system_type_id user_type_id schema_id max_length scale 
---- -------------- ------------ --------- ---------- ----- 
int  56             56           4         4          10
```

and that is the columntype, not if it is the primarykey.

There doesn't seem to be reliable way to find the primary key by means of the GetSchema call, AFAICT. Use the query provided by [Dan Guzman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47960587/578411).

Comment: This is really an amazing detective work. I don't know SQL so good so I wouldn't have come even half so far - and I've learnt a lot from your answer. It's a pity that they chose such a confusing name _KeyType_ that in other places is correctly called _DataType_. I will accept this answer because it goes to the very bottom of the magic number `56` which I wanted to verify and it also shows a few new tools how to this by my self in future - although as a _Plan B_ solution I will have to switch to what @DanGuzman suggested as my theory turned out to be false.

Answer (score 4):

The `KeyType` column appears to map to the column data type as enumerated by the SQL Server `sys.types` catalog view `system_type` column (value 56 is `int`). Consequently, this will not help identify the column as a member of the primary key.

There are multiple methods to get SQL Server primary key columns, including SMO and catalog view queries. Here's one example to get all the primary key columns in the database for SQL Server. If you need to support multiple DBMS products, you could instead use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` catalog views for DBMS products that implement those ANSI standard views.

```sql
SELECT 
      OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(i.object_id) AS SchemaName
    , OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id) AS TableName
    , c.name AS ColumnName
    , ic.key_ordinal AS KeyOrdinal
FROM sys.key_constraints AS kc
JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON i.object_id = kc.parent_object_id AND kc.name = i.name
JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
JOIN sys.columns AS c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
WHERE kc.type_desc = N'PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT'
ORDER BY
      SchemaName
    , TableName
    , KeyOrdinal;
```